# How to load and display SVG data by "raphael-svg-import"?

Tags: firefox, import, svg, raphael, inkscape

(using Raphael_2.01, WindowsXP, Firefox12.0)

Hello folks,

I can't load and display a SVG data by "raphael-svg-import" :(

I've made a SVG shape data by "Adobe FlashCS5" and "Adobe Wallaby" and checked it by Inkscape-ver0.46.

The shape is blue-gradient ball. Please see http://kie.nu/af2 .

With the sample of  https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import , I wrote the html and Raphael code:

```
window.onload = function () {

    paper = Raphael(0, 0, 800, 600); 
    paper.importSVG(SVG_data);// <======================= (* **)
}
```

The svg code can be viewed at http://pastebin.com/Dz1N8iiz  or http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/ucWUh/

When I ran the sample code of "raphael-svg-import"(Purple paint on a rectangle), it succeeded. But using above SVG data, Firefox doesn't show anything :(

What Should I do ?

Thanks.
Crane@Japan

Comment: ***** Sorry. The link of SVG_data is Japanese (http://kie.nu/af8). Please press "DOWNLOAD" button.

Comment: You have a lot of unaccepted answers. No one is gonna bother answering this. Also, a jsfiddle might be better to ilustrate the problem, rather than posting dubious download links.

Comment: Just so you know, it may make some users uncomfortable to download a data flle, especially from someone new to the site.  Use a code paste site like pastebin.com, or even better, an html/xml renderer like jsfiddle.com. I've updated your question with pointers to both.

Comment: Thank you so much mihai and Anthony.  I've tried to paste the svg_code (XML code) at this site, but the tags of this disappeared
 and I couldn't use the HTML code handle function of this site properly.  The future, I will use jsfiddle or  pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the function "importSVG()" can't take the argument which includes gradation parameters.

I've checked several SVG codes. When they have path and simple paint information, "importSVG()" can ran normally.
But one of them includes color gradation parameters, no shape appears.

So I think when we want to draw gradation shapes we must use the Raphael's gradient settings.

(for example: “r(0.25, 0.75)#fff-#000”)